# iPhone 7 won't force reset

Tags: iphone, restart

My iPhone 7 has been disabled from too many password attempts. I try to do a force/ hard reset but the apple logo just fades on and off. IS there anything I can do? I really don't want to have to go to the store since it is so far away from where I live. Any other ideas?

Comment: To clarify, if you attempt to force the device to restart by holding both the power and volume down buttons, the device will not return to the password entry screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting it into DFU mode. A google search should turn it up.

Steps to DFU Mode:

1. Plug your iPhone into your computer and open iTunes. It doesn’t matter if your iPhone is on or off.
2. Press and hold the Sleep / Wake Button and Home Button (iPhone 6s and below) or the volume down button (iPhone 7 and above) together for 8 seconds.
3. After 8 seconds, release the Sleep / Wake Button but continue to hold the Home Button (iPhone 6s and below) or the volume down button (iPhone 7 and above) until iTunes says “iTunes has detected an iPhone in recovery mode.”iTunes has detected an iPhone in recovery mode
4. Let go of the Home Button or volume down button. Your iPhone’s display will be completely black if you’ve successfully entered DFU mode. If it’s not, try again from the beginning.
5. Restore your iPhone using iTunes.

[Source](https://www.payetteforward.com/how-to-put-iphone-dfu-mode/)

Comment: Can you please post the instructions. This is not a full answer.

Comment: I'm actually gentle, because the instructions were: "A google search should turn it up." The edit was more to avoid this answer to be deleted.